# react-router redirect componentDidMount not firing

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm just getting into react/redux and I've been able to successfully call a login api and another api to retrieve a list of software packages. The api to retrieve the list of software packages should be called after successful login i.e., redirect to /packages route and call the api from componentDidMount(). The redirect works but componentDidMount() is only fired if I reload the page. What is the correct way to redirect and call the api to get the software packages using react-router?

***loginReducer.js***

```
import {Map,fromJS,List} from 'immutable';
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';
import initialState from './initialState';
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

const creds = Map({
  credentials: Map({
    authToken: null,
    details: Map({
      uuid: null,
      emailAddress: null,
      permissions: List(),
      roles: List(),
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      status: null
    }),
    refreshToken: null
  })
});

export default function loginReducer(state = creds.get('credentials'), action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
      hashHistory.push('/packages')
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

***Packages.jsx***

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import pureRender from 'pure-render-decorator';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {loadPackages} from '../../actions/packageActions';
import reducer from '../../reducers/rootReducer';
import PackageList from './PackageList';

export class Packages extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('loading packages'); // EDIT
    this.props.dispatch(loadPackages());
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-12">
        {this.props.results ?
        <PackageList results={this.props.results} /> :
        <h3>No Packages Available</h3>}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    packages: state.packages.get('packages'),
    results: state.packages.getIn(['packages','results'])
  };
}

export const PackagesContainer = connect(mapStateToProps)(Packages);
```

***index.jsx***

```
const routes = <Route component={App}>
  <Route path="/packages" component={PackagesContainer} />
  <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
</Route>;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hashHistory}>{routes}</Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: sounds like Packages.jsx is already mounted, but you didn't show the router code. Are you sure its not mounted?

Comment: I added console.log('loading packages'); and don't see the message until I reload /#/packages page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using browserHistory.push() for the redirect when I was using hashHistory in my router definition.